# jaudiotagger java - MP3AudioHeader can not be resolved

Tags: java, mp3

I am trying to use jaudiotagger for retriving id3 tags from mp3 file for my recent side project but I have run into this problem..I can't run the program because I get this error saying "MP3AudioHeader can not be resolved"..but I have imported everything that is needed as you can see...any suggestions would be helpful and here is the code I copied from the website

```
import org.jaudiotagger.*;
 public class mainClass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // the file we are going to read
    File oSourceFile = new File("/Users/tushar_chutani/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Fun_/We Are Young (feat. Janelle Monáe) - Single/01 We Are Young (feat. Janelle Monáe).mp3");

    MP3File f      = (Mp3File)AudioFileIO.read(oSourceFile);
    MP3AudioHeader audioHeader = f.getAudioHeader();
    audioHeader.getTrackLength();
    audioHeader.getSampleRateAsNumber();
    mp3AudioHeader.getChannels();
    mp3AudioHeader.isVariableBitRate();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct ,the mistake is that ,its not (Mp3File) its (MP3File) 'p' should be in capital letter. so correct is:-

```
MP3File f  = (MP3File)AudioFileIO.read(oSourceFile);
```